# Show day and time according to google adsense

Tags: php, jquery

```
<div id="cp_opening_hours">
<h3 class="howtoreach openinghrs">Opening Hours</h3>
<span>Monday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Tuesday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Wednesday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Thursday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Friday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Saturday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Sunday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span></div>
```

....

```
var dayNames = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
 var nData = new Date();

      jQuery( "#cp_opening_hours span" ).each(function(i)   { 

        var to_day=jQuery(this).text();

        to_day_new=to_day.split(" ");

        to_day_new1=to_day_new[0].split(':');


        span_pos=dayNames.lastIndexOf(dayNames[nData.getDay()]);

        span_val=jQuery("#cp_opening_hours span:nth-of-type("+span_pos+")").text();

        if(span_val!=undefined){jQuery("#thelanguage_new").append('<span>'+span_val+'</span>');}
        jQuery("#cp_opening_hours span:nth-of-type("+span_pos+")").remove();


        if(to_day_new1[0]=='Sunday')
        {

            jQuery(this).remove();
            to_day_new_time=to_day.split(':');

            main_today_time=to_day_new_time[1];

             if(main_today_time=="Closed")
            {
            jQuery('#cp_opening_hours div').prepend('<span class="closed">Today: '+main_today_time+'<br/></span>');

            }
            else
            {
                jQuery('#cp_opening_hours div').prepend('<span class="open">Open Today: '+main_today_time+'<br/></span>');
            }  


        }


    });  
    jQuery("#thelanguage_new p:nth-of-type(1)").remove();
```

I want to show the day and time for today bases if today is Wednesday .so i want like this

```
<div id="cp_opening_hours">
<h3 class="howtoreach openinghrs">Opening Hours</h3>

<span>Open Today: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Thursday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Friday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Saturday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Sunday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Monday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span>
<span>Tuesday: 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM<br></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this manipulation - I can give you a more elegant solution later

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Gg93D/)

```
var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var today = new Date();
var fromToday = dayNames.slice(today.getDay());
var endDates = dayNames.slice(0,today.getDay());
var dayNamesSorted = fromToday.concat(endDates);
var $div = $("#cp_opening_hours");
$div.html('<h3 class="howtoreach openinghrs">Opening Hours</h3>');
$.each(dayNamesSorted,function(i,day) {
  $div.append('<span>'+(i===0?"Today":day)+' '+': 10.30 AM - 9.30 PM</span><br/>'); 
});
```